# UITableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath does not trigger scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview

I have my code that want to defer to call `reloadData` after scrolling animation finishes.

1. When data source is updated `performNextUpdate` will be called.
2. I will `performNextUpdate` only if it's not playing the scrolling animation.
3. After I call `reloadData`, I then call `scrollToRowAtIndexPath` at last cell, to play scrolling animation.
4. I know that `didEndScrollingAnimation` will not be triggered if the cell is already in the position where it should scroll to. So I have `canScrollToBottomAtIndexPath` to check.
5. After scrolling animation finishes, I will call `performNextUpdate` again, from `pendingDataSource` (if exist).

My problem is, rarely `scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation` is not triggered. So `animateScrolling = YES`, forever.  Even if there's `pendingDataSource`, the app will no longer `reloadData`.

Does anyone know what can cause `scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation` not triggered when calling `scrollToRowAtIndexPath:` ?

---

Here my example code,

```
- (void)performNextUpdate {
    if (self.pendingDataSource && !self.animateScrolling) {
        self.dataSource = self.pendingDataSource;
        [self.tableView reloadData];
        [self animateScrollToBottomIfNeeded];
    }
}

- (void)animateScrollToBottomIfNeeded {
    if ([self canScrollToBottomAtIndexPath:indexPath]) {
        self.animateScrolling = YES;
        [self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:lastIndexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom animated:YES];
        // Wait for didEndScrollingAnimation to call before performing the next update
    } else {
        // Can perform the next update immediately, since there's no need to scroll.
        self.animateScrolling = NO;
        [self performNextUpdate];
    }
}

// Sometimes this function is not triggered. 
- (void)scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    self.animateScrolling = NO;
    [self performNextUpdate];
}

- (BOOL)canScrollToBottomAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (!indexPath) {
        return NO;
    }
    if ((self.tableView.tracking || self.tableView.dragging) && !self.tableView.isDecelerating) {
        return NO;
    }
    CGRect viewPort = CGRectMake(self.tableView.contentOffset.x, self.tableView.contentOffset.y, self.tableView.bounds.size.width, self.tableView.bounds.size.height);
    CGRect visibleViewPort = UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(viewPort, self.tableView.contentInset);
    CGRect cellRect = [self.tableView rectForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    if (CGRectEqualToRect(cellRect, CGRectZero)) {
        // If indexPath is invalid, it will return CGRectZero.
        return NO;
    } else {
        return !CGRectContainsRect(visibleViewPort, cellRect);
    }
}
```

Comment: ```scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation``` is kind of tricky thing, it's usually triggered by a fling gesture, you can scroll the table all the way down without triggering this delegate method if you don't lift your finger. I always avoided this delegate method since is soooo confusing, I usually go with ```scrollViewDidScroll```, but in your case it won't properly work ( I think).

Comment: Yeah, it won't work `scrollViewDidScroll` is not called, when set contentOffset manually.